# Record store in lwuit

Tags: lwuit

Does LWUIT have an implementation for j2me record store?

I have made a lwuit app which uses j2me recordstore. However, I feel that using lwuit api without jumping into j2me api would help make the app more portable. Am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, LWUIT has a record store. Check `Storage` Class of LWUIT IO, but this is only available in LWUIT 1.5.

Yes, it would make it more portable.

Answer (score 1):

You no need LWUIT for RS

```
public static void writeDataToRecordStore(byte[] aData, final String aDir) {
    if (aData == null) {
        return;
    }
    RecordStore iRecord = null;
    try {
        iRecord = RecordStore.openRecordStore(aDir, true);
        if (iRecord.getNumRecords() > 0) {
            iRecord.setRecord(1, aData, 0, aData.length);
        } else {
            iRecord.addRecord(aData, 0, aData.length);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    } finally {
        if (iRecord != null) {
            try {
                iRecord.closeRecordStore();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            iRecord = null;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Read data from Record Store
 *
 * @param aDir
 * @return
 */
public static byte[] readDataFromRecordStore(final String aDir) {
    RecordStore iReccord = null;
    try {
        iReccord = RecordStore.openRecordStore(aDir, false);
        if (iReccord.getNumRecords() > 0) {
            // Has data
            return iReccord.getRecord(1);
        }
    } catch (Exception otherEx) {
    } finally {
        if (iReccord != null) {
            try {
                iReccord.closeRecordStore();
            } catch (Exception ex1) {
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use J2ME record store for this i.e. RMS record management store.

Answer (score 0):

Lwuit using Record Store in HTML Component.
And I think, using record store is not related with LWUIT. They both separate function. LWUIT is for User Interface / View, record store is for data / model.